# How to do that without dataset to rdd conversion?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

Could someone help me how to avoid rdd conversion?

```
val qksDistribution: Array[((String, Int), Long)] = tripDataset
      .map(i => ((i.getFirstPoint.getQk.substring(0, QK_PARTITION_LEVEL), i.getProviderId), 1L))
      .rdd
      .reduceByKey(_+_)
      .filter(_._2>maxCountInPartition/10)
      .collect
```

Comment: You can use [`groupByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) and then pass the reduce function. In any case, why do you want to avoid the `rdd` transformation?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Because I am not really understand how that works, I've expect a lot of object allocations during such transformation

Comment: can you provide the schema that the map returns?

Comment: Yeah it may instantiate a few things, but I do not think it would be much of a problem. Anyways, the `groupByKey` is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val qksDistribution: Array[((String, Int), Long)] = tripDataset
      .map(i => (i.getFirstPoint.getQk.substring(0, QK_PARTITION_LEVEL), i.getProviderId)) // no need to add the 1
      .groupByKey(x => x) //similar to key by
      .count // you wanted to count per key
      .filter(_._2>maxCountInPartition/10)
      .collect
```

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename